# <ng-select> fails to bind data show empty input box

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms

this is data to bind

```
private category: Array<object> = [
     { "id": 1, "text": "Table" },
     { "id": 2, "text": "Chair" },
     { "id": 3, "text": "Light" }
 ];

<ng-select [items]="category"  placeholder="No city selected">
</ng-select>
```

This is the HTML part I don't know what I am wrong. It only creates a black input box

Comment: Its in Angular2

Comment: are you using a library of some kind here? ng-select is an angularjs directive. angular 2 uses ngFor with an options tag.

Comment: You need to replace [items] with [options].